# Unable to replace a line using sed

Tags: sed, text-processing

I have a file which has the below lines-

```
[arakoon_scaler_thresholds]
checker_loop_time = 3600
```

I want to replace the above 2 lines with the below line -

```
[arakoon_scaler_thresholds]
checker_loop_time = 60
```

I am using the below command but changes are not taking place.

```
sed -i "s/arakoon_scaler_thresholds\nchecker_loop_time = 3600/arakoon_scaler_thresholds\nchecker_loop_time = 60/g" file.ini
```

**Note** There are multiple parameters with name `checker_loop_time`, I want to change only that `checker_loop_time` which is under the section `[arakoon_scaler_thresholds]`

Comment: Out of the box, `sed` only examines a single line at a time. Aside from that, your search expression looks for the keyword adjacent to a newline, whereas in your example, it is followed by a right square bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and once it is okay, use the `-i` option for inplace editing

```
$ cat ip.txt 
checker_loop_time = 5463

[arakoon_scaler_thresholds]
checker_loop_time = 3600
checker_loop_time = 766

$ sed -E '/arakoon_scaler_thresholds/{N;s/(checker_loop_time\s*=\s*)3600/\160/}' ip.txt 
checker_loop_time = 5463

[arakoon_scaler_thresholds]
checker_loop_time = 60
checker_loop_time = 766
```

This searches for `arakoon_scaler_thresholds`, then gets next line with `N` and then performs the required search and replace

You can also use `awk`

```
$ awk 'p ~ /arakoon_scaler_thresholds/{sub("checker_loop_time = 3600","checker_loop_time = 60")} {p=$0}1' ip.txt 
checker_loop_time = 5463

[arakoon_scaler_thresholds]
checker_loop_time = 60
checker_loop_time = 766
```

where previous line is saved in a variable

Comment: Thanks a lot Sundeep, I used the below command- sudo sed -E -i '/arakoon_scaler_thresholds/{N;s/(checker_loop_time\s*=\s*)3600/checker_loop_time = 60/}'